# Dropdown to select posts by month and then displaying those posts in the archive page

Tags: archives

I get how to select posts by month with a dropwdown, according to the Codex:

```
      <select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ); ?></option> 
        <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
      </select>
```

What is the correct query parameter, in the archive page where this dropdown redirects so that I can only see posts from that selected month? I'm only seeing things like:

```
'type' => 'monthly'
```

But that does not work.